# Ag-Grid header Component adding custom header templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ag-grid

I'm still using Angular 1.x and ag-Grid (non-enterprise).

But I'm trying to add tooltips from angular ui-bootstrap. So I need to add an attribute to all headers: "uib-tooltip='headerValue' "

The issue is that it wants me to implement a whole new component. But the example component they put on the ag-grid website is super complicated and different from the default functionality. Why isn't there an easy way of doing these things?

Why deprecate headerTemplate?

So even if I want a slight change from the default headers, I basically need to take over responsibility for everything. And I don't even have the original version of header component as example code.

I just want to add some new HTML to the header that doesn't involve taking responsibility for sorting, field, menu etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old but...I was in this exact situation, where I was wondering why it wasn't provided... I went ahead and built my own which wasn't extremely hard. Since I think someone might find a default header component useful: here's one that is essentially the default

Note you'll need font awesome for the icons and make sure to use the custom component in your column options.

```
    function customHeaderComponent() {
    }

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.init = function (agParams) {
        this.agParams = agParams;
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = '' +
            '<span class="customHeaderLabel">' + this.agParams.displayName + '</span> ' +
            '<span class="customSortDownLabel inactive"><i class="fa fa-caret-down""></i> </span>' +
            '<span class="customSortUpLabel inactive"><i class="fa fa-caret-up""></i> </span>'+
            '<span class="customFilterLabel inactive"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> </span>'+
            '<span class="customHeaderMenuButton"><i class="fa fa-tasks""></i></span>'
        ;

        this.eMenuButton = this.eGui.querySelector(".customHeaderMenuButton");
        this.eLabel = this.eGui.querySelector(".customHeaderLabel");
        this.eSortDownButton = this.eGui.querySelector(".customSortDownLabel");
        this.eSortUpButton = this.eGui.querySelector(".customSortUpLabel");
        this.eFilterInd = this.eGui.querySelector(".customFilterLabel");


        if (this.agParams.enableMenu) {
            this.onMenuClickListener = this.onMenuClick.bind(this);
            this.eMenuButton.addEventListener('click', this.onMenuClickListener);
        } else {
            this.eGui.removeChild(this.eMenuButton);
        }

        if (this.agParams.enableSorting) {
            this.eLabel.addEventListener('click', this.changeSort.bind(this));

            this.onSortChangedListener = this.onSortChanged.bind(this);
            this.agParams.column.addEventListener('sortChanged', this.onSortChangedListener);
            this.onSortChanged();
        }
        var self = this;
        self.eFilterInd.hidden = !self.agParams.column.isFilterActive();
        this.agParams.column.addEventListener('filterChanged', function() {
            self.eFilterInd.hidden = !self.agParams.column.isFilterActive();
        });

    };

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.changeSort = function (event) {
        this.agParams.progressSort(event);
    }


    customHeaderComponent.prototype.onSortChanged = function () {
        function deactivate(toDeactivateItems) {
            toDeactivateItems.forEach(function (toDeactivate) {
                toDeactivate.hidden = true;
            });
        }

        function activate(toActivate) {
            toActivate.hidden = false;
        }

        if (this.agParams.column.isSortAscending()) {
            deactivate([this.eSortUpButton]);
            activate(this.eSortDownButton)
        } else if (this.agParams.column.isSortDescending()) {
            deactivate([this.eSortDownButton]);
            activate(this.eSortUpButton)
        } else {
            deactivate([this.eSortUpButton, this.eSortDownButton]);
        }
    };

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.getGui = function () {
        return this.eGui;
    };

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.onMenuClick = function () {
        this.agParams.showColumnMenu(this.eMenuButton);
    };

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.onSortRequested = function (order, event) {
        this.agParams.setSort(order, event.shiftKey);
    };

    customHeaderComponent.prototype.destroy = function () {
        if (this.onMenuClickListener) {
            this.eMenuButton.removeEventListener('click', this.onMenuClickListener)
        }
    };
```

Comment: Yes the main issue is that there is a ton of code to write, and there's two ways to write it (one old, one new with ES script).

Comment: How do we use Angular.js templates inside the header? I used to have `<span ng-bind="colDef.headerName"></span>` and does not seem to work when using Header Component. No documentation...