# Ag-Grid Header Component with AngularJS compiled template

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I would like to use an Ag-Grid Header Component in a grid on my AngularJS (v1.6.8) page. I can get the component working using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727119/3247194), but it does not appear to compile AngularJS like the deprecated headerCellRenderer did.

How can I make the Header Component compile AngularJS?

See here for a basic example: https://embed.plnkr.co/mUmNL1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$compile` service for that.

```
getTemplate = function () {
  var str = $compile('<span ng-click="alertMsg()">{{getLabel()}}</span>')($scope)[0];
  return str;
};
```

Have a look at this plunk: [ag-grid angularjs custom header component](https://plnkr.co/edit/ng6KQh)

Also, you would need to make few changes in `CustomerHeader`'s `init` function as per this example: [Angular 1.x and ag-Grid Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/#ng1Components)

```
MakeHeaderComp.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eGui.innerHTML = '=> {{params.displayName}}';

    // create and compile AngularJS scope for this component
    this.$scope = $scope.$new();
    $compile(this.eGui)(this.$scope);
    this.$scope.params = params;
    // in case we are running outside of angular (ie in an ag-grid started VM turn)
    // we call $apply. we put in timeout in case we are inside apply already.
    setTimeout(this.$scope.$apply.bind(this.$scope), 0);
};
```